# Is this still a derivative?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm reading through ["Fast Exact Multiplication by the Hessian", Neural Computation, 1994](http://www.bcl.hamilton.ie/~barak/papers/nc-hessian.pdf), and they have this (equation 2):

[image]

Where $w$ is a vector and $\nabla_w$ is the gradient of $E$ (a scalar) w.r.t. $w$,  $H$ is the hessian of $E$ w.r.t. $w$, $v$ is a vector, and $r$ is a scalar.

My question is how they were able to equate that limit with the derivative. For scalar-valued functions, I know the derivative is defined as

$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{f(x + \epsilon) - f(x)}{\epsilon}$$

However, the form of their equation is a little different because of the vector $v$. I don't know enough about the definition of derivatives for vector functions to see why it's right.

Is this usage of limits correct? If so, why? How does the definition of a derivative generalize to functions with vector inputs?

Comment: Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative)

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the vector equation as three independent scalar ones by splitting the components.

The fact that the function argument is a vector plays no role, as the independent variable is the scalar $r$ (though by the chain rule you will get the dot product of $\mathbb v$ with the gradients of the gradient components).

Answer (score 0):

A gradient of a scalar field outputs a vector. Differentiation for vectors works in similar fashion as for regular single-variable functions, you just derive every component of the vector. In a way, you can see this as the regular limit definition of the derivative, but then the function has been replaced by a vector. Notice that the function may depends on multiple variables, so a partial derivative has been used.

As Yves Daoust noticed, you can simply represent a vector (take as an example the position vector $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$ as the following object, if I select a cartesian base:
$ \frac{d\vec{r}}{dx}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x \hat{i} + y \hat{j} + z \hat{k} ) $ and by linearity of the differentiation operation (as a linear operator on vector spaces) $ \frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial}{ \partial x} x \hat{i} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} y \hat{j} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} z \hat{k}  $. It is true that $\epsilon - \delta$ proofs of limits do take into account that you have multiple variables, but this is often a simple generalisation, it is one of the wonders of multivariable calculus/vector caclulus that there exists a natural extension of single-variable calculus.

See: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/VectorFcnsCalculus.aspx